# How to send the file using php CURL

Tags: php, curl

Now I am uploading the file to the one sites. It works well. But I want to upload the file to the another site.  For example if I upload the file to the http://example.com and at the same time I want to upload that http://example2.com.

The file is image.  SO I use the code like this.

```
function SendFileToMobile($image_path, $target_url){

   $file_name_with_full_path = realpath($image_path);

   $post = array('extra_info' => $image_path,'img'=>$file_name_with_full_path);
   $ch = curl_init();
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$target_url);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,1);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
   $result=curl_exec ($ch);
   curl_close ($ch);
}
```

And the accept file is like this.

```
$imagePath = "image/user/";

$allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png", "GIF", "JPEG", "JPG", "PNG");
$temp = explode(".", $_FILES["img"]["name"]);
$extension = end($temp);

//Check write Access to Directory

if(!is_writable($imagePath)){
    $response = Array(
        "status" => 'error',
        "message" => 'Can`t upload File; no write Access',
        "path" => $imagePath
    );
    print json_encode($response);
    return;
}

if ( in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
  {
  if ($_FILES["img"]["error"] > 0)
    {
         $response = array(
            "status" => 'error',
            "message" => 'ERROR Return Code: '. $_FILES["img"]["error"],
        );          
    }
  else
    {

      $filename = $_FILES["img"]["tmp_name"];
      list($width, $height) = getimagesize( $filename );

      move_uploaded_file($filename,  $imagePath . $_FILES["img"]["name"]);

      $response = array(
        "status" => 'success',
        "url" => $imagePath.$_FILES["img"]["name"],
        "width" => $width,
        "height" => $height
      );

    }
  }
else
  {
   $response = array(
        "status" => 'error',
        "message" => 'something went wrong, most likely file is to large for upload. check upload_max_filesize, post_max_size and memory_limit in you php.ini',
    );
  }

  print json_encode($response);
```

But unfortunately it does not works. It returns the error message like this.

> something went wrong, most likely file is to large for upload. check upload_max_filesize, post_max_size and memory_limit in you php.ini

Please help me if anyone what is error.

Comment: the message is clear, have you checked `upload_max_filesize`?

Comment: Thanks. But that file is already uploaded one site. If it is bigger than upload_max_filesize, how it can be uploaded?